# Passport jwt vs passport local session

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

I use the library Express-session and Passport.

in this case I want to create a React SPA website, but I am confused by the correct system security.

I see there are many ways to authenticate and this is what makes me confused.

in the passport there are 2 authentication: **Passport-jwt** and **Passport-local**

because I use an Express session I chose to use passport-local.

**do I still need to use a passport-jwt? for each request that is inserted into the headers like this to indicate the user is logged in?**

```
const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = keys.passport.secretOrPrivateKey;

    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,(jwt_payload,done)=>{
        let queryFindAdmin = 'select * from admin where id = ?';
        db.query(queryFindAdmin,[jwt_payload.id],(err,result)=>{
            if(err) return done(err,null);
            if(result.length > 0){
                console.log(result);
                return done(null, result[0]);
            }
            return done(null, false);
        })
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, If you are using sessions you by definition do not need JWT tokens. JWT tokens are an alternative to sessions.